# Solr 7.5 does not return content field

Tags: search, solr

I index a folder with PHP docs. now when I do query I get results as

```
{
    "id":"<getting value>",
    "stream_size":[3984],
    "x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
      "org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser"],
    "stream_content_type":["application/octet-stream"],
    "viewport":["width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"],
    "content_encoding":["windows-1252"],
    "resourcename":["value"],
    "content_type":["text/html; charset=windows-1252"],`enter code here`
    "_version_":1768}
```

I am not getting the content here in any field. Any idea how to get actual text result here?

Comment: check your schema file ...does it have stored = true for the fields where you want the actual text...

Comment: also for all your fields multivalue is true...Check if it really requires for your field otherwise make it false.

Answer (score 0):

Your fields must be missing the `stored` attribute.

Please add the `stored=true` for the fields which you want to have in the response.

`stored = true` is required if you need read the values/content of a field from the index. For example, if you like to use highlighting feature or if you like to use solr as a database, and not just as a search index.

If `stored = true` : It simply store the original content and return the original content, if needed.

Please refer for more info : [Solr Documentation for field defination](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/defining-fields.html)